# Randomly replace elements in a dictionary lists based on another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, random

It looks like a game but I need this to evaluate a model I'm working on. Need some help...
I have a dictionary with lists as values. I need to replace only one element in each list at a random position with an element in `my_list` but which is not present in the list.
Then I need to print which letters were swapped preferably as a list of tuples showing each key from the original dictionary.
My code so far, which doesn't work as needed...:

```
my_list=[['a','b','c','d','e','q'],['f','j','k','l','m','n'],['o','p','r','s','t','k'], ['e','s','w','x','h','z']]
my_dict = {0:['a','d','f'], 1:['o','t','e'], 2:['m', 'j', 'k'],3:['d','z','f']}
all_letters = set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(my_list))

replace_index = np.random.randint(0,3,4)
print(replace_index)
dict_out = my_dict.copy()
replacements = []
for key, terms in enumerate(my_list):
    print(key)
    print(terms)
    other_letters = all_words.difference(terms)
    print(other_letters)
    replacement = np.random.choice(list(other_letters))
    print(replacement)
    replacements.append((terms[replace_index[key]], replacement))
    print(replacements)
    dict_out[replace_index[key]] = replacement
    print(dict_out)
print(replacements) # [(o,('a','c')...]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you could do something like this:

```
import numpy as np

for i, k in enumerate(my_dict):
    # Pick a random element of your list in each key of my_dict:
    original = my_dict[k][np.random.randint(0, len(my_dict[i]))]
     # Pick a random element of the corresponding list, that is not in the my_dict key
    replacement = np.random.choice(list(set(my_list[i]) - set(my_dict[k])), 1)[0]
    # Replace the original for the replacement
    my_dict[k][my_dict[i].index(original)] = replacement
    # Print what was switched
    print((k,(original, replacement)))
```

The output is:

```
(0, ('a', 'e'))
(1, ('t', 'm'))
(2, ('m', 't'))
(3, ('f', 'h'))
```

And your `my_dict` now looks like:

```
{0: ['e', 'd', 'f'], 1: ['o', 'm', 'e'], 2: ['t', 'j', 'k'], 3: ['d', 'z', 'h']}
```